# issue submitting app for review - already submitted

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer

So i have uploaded the app via xcode however when i go to submit the app via appstoreconnect.apple.com i get the following error.

[image]

but when i go to re-upload it, seems it is already uploaded. So what have I missed.
[image]
It says it has been delivered - is there a processing time?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is right on the screen in the image you uploaded. You've already uploaded a binary with the same BUILD #.

Log into iTunes Connect and either select the uploaded build... it will take a few minutes to process before it is available, OR if you have invalidated that and are uploading a new one. Go to you Project in Xcode and on the General Tab for the Target, bump the build number.[image]

Comment: then why can't I submit for review?

Comment: On App Store Connect, goto the "activity" tab for that App and see what the status of the build you have already uploaded is. If it is finished being processed you should be able to select that build as the build you want to submit for Review. Until you have selected a build there isn't anything to review :)

Comment: what if there is no build showing? yet on transporter it says it has been delivered?

Comment: You will have to poke around ON the iTunes Connect site. Or bump your build number up by 1 and try uploading again.

Comment: Am getting invalid binary

Comment: Well that is something else, you better try re-building your app and examining what is going on on xcode console during the build and upload process. But their is your essential problem. Probably why there is no selectable build on iTunes Connect.

Comment: solved it - I wish apple would of said "Check your emails" GRRR